# square root of a Riemannian metric

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, compact-manifolds

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. Taking a smooth vector field $X$, there is an associated smooth function $$g(X,X):M\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^+, \quad p\longmapsto g_p(X_p,X_p)\geq 0.$$ I would like to know if there are a finite number of smooth functions $f_i$ $\in$ $C^{\infty}(M)$ such that $$g(X,X)=\sum_i f^2_i.$$

Comment: You can do it at least locally by using an orthonormal frame.

Comment: @timur how exactly? because if it is true that you are saying then adding the hypothesis "orientable" would be enough to do it globally, right?

Comment: I'm missing something. If $X$ is non-vanishing, just take $f_1 = \sqrt{g(X,X)}$. Or the point of the question is precisely to deal with the singularities of $X$?

Comment: Yes. $X$ can be any smooth vector field.

Comment: I don't think orientable would be enough. For example, the sphere is orientable but you can't find a global orthonormal frame (or can you?).

Comment: @timur, yes, you right

Comment: However, what if you try to stick together many orthonormal frames by using a partition of unity?